# Passing data structures from Python to Java using Jython

Tags: java, python, jython-2.5

This seems like a really basic question, but I haven't been able to find the answer...

I have a Java web app built with GWT.  It needs to call some code that's written in Python.  I've followed the tutorial and written an object factory for the methods that use simple data types.

However, one of the python methods includes this code:

```
titles_ranked = []
 for i in range(len(sort_index)):
     doc['title'] = self.titles[sort_index[i]][0][0]
     doc['role'] = self.RDS[:,sort_index[i]].toarray().reshape(6,)
     titles_ranked.append(doc.copy())
 return titles_ranked
```

How can I represent this in the Java wrapper class so that I can access it from Java?  Alternatively, do I need to use some other data structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, it's a PyArray.